# Jython use private python library

Tags: java, python, jython

I have a python library I wrote that needs to be used in a java project. My java code will access the python code by using Jython as the interface between java and python. I will install Jython using maven. How would I install my python library from git so that it is available to Jython?

Comment: I don't get your question. "I have a python library I wrote that needs to be used in a Java project." meaning you want to call Jython functions using Java?

Then you said " I'm planning to use Jython to use the python library from my code". What exactly are you trying to do with Jython?

Comment: I updated my question, hopefully it's more clear